# Adding a category to AppDelegate to implement a method from UIAplicationDelegate protocol

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, push-notification

I am developing a Cocoa Touch Framework, I want to receive remote notifications from APNS and I found that (after all the process it needs to establish communication with APNS) I have to catch notifications inside `application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:` method. However, I want to let the less work possible to the IOS developer, so I been wondering.

- Is it possible to create a category of the AppDelegate inside my framework (Since it
  already has an extension when a new app is created) in order to
  implement this method ?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say it's not needed. What you can do here is create some function in your with the same params as in `application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:` and make it available for the possible developer to call from your Framework.

Many frameworks are working that way like FacebookSDK.
For example, my code in AppDelegate for opening/handling URL:

```
func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
    let fbHandled: Bool = ApplicationDelegate.shared.application(app,
                                                               open: url,
                                                               sourceApplication: options[.sourceApplication] as? String,
                                                               annotation: options[.annotation])
    return fbHandled
}
```

You could see that Facebook just provide me some public methods to handle links inside their SDK. It's a better solution than make implicit handling for something that the developer might be needed aware of and be available to change in his code.

Comment: I did not took that aproach in consideration, I really appreciate it.